# How to disable hover effect on mobile device for jQuery Autocomplete Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

We are using [Autocomplete Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) to quickly find and select from a pre-populated list of values as user type.

I want to disable the hover effect for mobile mode. We are overriding `ui-state-active` class to apply it whenever a user hovers on UI menu dropdown.

How can disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answere.

We can use below code.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
          $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover mouseenter');
      }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286685/autocomplete-requires-you-to-click-twice-in-ios-after-update-to-1-11-0/32817003)