Add li items into jQuery UI Autocomplete so the native click handler works, with 2 optional parameters
Apologies in advance if the question sounds confusing. The code is complex so I'm trying to balance clarity without providing too many unnecessary details.
I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete widget with an AJAX source. The result contains a list item at the bottom of the menu with a data-attribute corresponding to a database primary key, used to load more results, from the same AJAX source with an added parameter, show_more.
I add these new items in a separate click handler function, and use $('.ui-menu ul').append(li-items) to the rendered list to add the new items right after the list item which was just clicked, but above other term  search results. Clicking or using the arrow keys and enter on these added items produces ui.item == undefined in the native select method. We use an additive search scheme so I'm using a separate click-handler to get the url query sting parameters, and add the new url, if needed. That works fine except for using the keyboard to arrow key->enter, which is a requirement of the project. Using the arrow keys in the menu highlights the added links but does not select them.
There are 2 different optional inputs. The autocomplete input itself, and the clicked autocomplete item. We want to send the input data every time to AJAX, but the show_more data would only be sent with the menu item click event.
How can I append the rendered menu in such a way that the native select handler for clicks and keyboard events works out of the box?
function searchClickHandler(url) {
    if (!url || url == '') { return false; }
    // 1. get the query string parameters, make an object
    // 2. get the url argument, make key value
    // loop through object, add new url if needed, construct new_url then redirect
    window.location = new_url;
    return false;
}


function initAutoComplete() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // fixes issue where selecting an autocomplete suggestion on iPad required 2 clicks
            // Also prevents html from populating the autocomplete input
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286685/autocomplete-requires-you-to-click-twice-in-ios-after-update-to-1-11-0
            $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover mouseenter');
        },
        source: "/ac_controller/autocompleteajax",
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, li) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    })
        .autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return renderItemFun(ul, item);
        };
}

function renderItemFun(ul, item) {
    if (item.prettymeta == 'see more recent searches' && !Object.hasOwn(item, 'heading')) {
        return $("<li>")
            .append(
                `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper add-new-results d-flex" data-more="${item.show_more}">
                <span class="ac-processed-item w-100 text-center smaller"><span class="see-more-link blue underline">see more recent searches</span></span>
            </a>
        `).appendTo(ul);
    } else {
        return $("<li>").append(`<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="${item.url}" style="outline: none;">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center" style="margin: 3px 0px;">
                <span class="ac-processed-item">${item.label}</span>
            </div>
        </a>`).appendTo(ul);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initAutoComplete();
    $('body').on('click', '.ui-menu-item a:not(.add-new-results)', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        searchClickHandler(url);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.add-new-results', function (e) {
        let original = $(this);
        let start = $(this).data('more');
        let term = $('#search').val();

        $.get(
            `/ac_controller/autocompleteajax/`,
            { 'term': term, 'show_more': start },
            function (data) {
                let recents = JSON.parse(data);
                let html = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < recents.length; i++) {
                    if (Object.hasOwn(recents[i], 'heading')) { continue; }
                    if (recents[i].metatype == 'recent_search' && recents[i].url != 'javascript:void(0);') {
                        html += `<li class="ui-menu-item">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="${recents[i].url}">
                                        <span class="ac-processed-item">${recents[i].label}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>`;
                    } else if (recents[i].prettymeta == 'see more recent searches' && Object.hasOwn(recents[i], 'show_more')) {
                        html += `<li class="ui-menu-item">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper add-new-results" data-more="${recents[i].show_more}">
                                        <span class="ac-processed-item"><span>see more recent searches</span></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>`;
                    }
                }
                original.closest('li').after(html);
                original.closest('li').remove();
                $("#search").addClass('active');
            }
        );
    });
});


How are you adding additional items to the select? Quite a bit of information seems to be missing, might also try to create a stack snippet by using the <> icon on the editor toolbar.

Thank you @PaulT, the AJAX response has a lot of variables so I added a reduced example of the code itself. I hope this clarifies what I'm asking.
